# How cand I find the coordinates of a rectangle's diagonal in MATLAB or C language?

Tags: c, matlab, plot

I need to write a program that creates a rectangle from user inputted values for the length and width and returns a set of X and Y coordinates for every 0.25mm point on the rectangle's diagonal. It may sound ambiguous, but I'll explain in the following lines.

For example, the user will input the following values: 0.500 mm in length and 0.800 mm in width. The program will then create a rectangle based on these values, generate two intersecting diagonals from each corner of the rectangle, calculate the length of the diagonal, mark their point of intersection and divide the total length of the diagonal by two, thus marking the length of a segment from each corner of the rectangle to the diagonals's point of intersection.

After this, the rectangle needs to be plotted, the origin beeing one of the lower corners of the rectangle. 
Then, I need to map every 0.25 mm point of this diagonal in order to get its coordinates; more exactly, from the origin (corner), until the first end of a 0.25 mm segment - the end of the segment would be the coordinates I need. 
Then, the program should repeat the procedure for the next 0.25 mm segment of this diagonal and mark again the end of the segment with its coordinates. This instruction would stop when the point of intersection is reached.

The input would need to be something like:

```
Introduce a value for length:
Introduce a value for width:
```

And the output would need to be something like:

```
Seg.A: X coord. Y coord.
Seg B: X coord. Y coord
```

I created the image below to help me explain my intentions better.

[image: graph]

I thought about writing the program in Matlab (octave) and the convert it to C to run in a simple command-line .exe app. Except Matlab and some basic C, I have no additional knowledge whatsoever about programming. This program would help me predict the movement of certain bones on an X and Y plane after some constant mechanical stimulus is applied upon them.

Comment: Isn't it a pure geometry here? And it can be solved analytically much faster than this kind of numerical approximation..

Comment: In a way it is, but my lacking programming experience is a huge impediment. If I do it on paper, it's easy for one bone, but I have to predict the movements for more than 50 and design a plan which involves other movements too, not just translation movement. So finding these parameters as fast as possible is my main goal.

Comment: It has nothing to do with a programming as stated. Can you express the points mathematically? If you can't, no programming experience will help.

Comment: I think it can since the program needs to mark the 0,25 mm point of the diagonal and the communicate its coordinates. The problem comes in making the program mark the end of that 0.25 mm segment correctly.

Comment: _"I thought about writing the program in Matlab (octave) and the convert it to C to run in a simple command-line .exe app"_. I am sorry but this makes no sense. First, you cannot run C code from the command-line. You can write code in C and compile it to a .exe file. You can also run compiled Matlab code (if octave has a compiler), but this has nothing to do with C. Further, you can use tools to convert Matlab code to C code and compile it, even though I do not know why the intermediary step is necessary (except for in case Octave has a converter but no compiler).

Comment: By _command line_ I referred to _no mouse, no GUI, just the CMD_, but the part with _.exe app_  which should've done said enough about my final intention. I thought that I could experiment with Matlab and the compile the program into a .exe file so I can use it every day with just two clicks, instead of running matlab everytime I'll need to use this program.

Comment: The distance to the intersection is `d=0.5*sqrt(length*length+ width* width)`; for any distance `r`at the diagonal you can calculate the corresponding coordinates as `x = r*width/(2*d)` and `y = r*length/(2*d)`, respectively.

Comment: If you are wondering about the actual formula, ask at: http://math.stackexchange.com/. Once you have that part straight, you could try to implement it in C and then ask here. Pure math questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calculate de mean (sum divided by two) of the vectors pointing to opossed vertex and you will get the requested value.  No need to do numerical approximations, as the diagonals are by definition linear.  Center will be at `(X1 + X2)/2`  being `X1` and `X2` vectors pointing to opposed vertex (for example, lower left and upper right, or lower right and upper left)

By the way, if you only have de dimensions of the rectangle... the center (or the crossing point of the two diagonals, as it is the same) will be at `(width/2, height/2)` position relative to the rectangle's origin, always)

Comment: _By the way, if you only have de dimensions of the rectangle... the center (or the crossing point of the two diagonals, as it is the same) will be at (width/2, height/2) position relative to the rectangle's origin, always)_ 

That was my thought also, but I wrote the question at a moment when I was exhausted from school work and didn't think the question too much. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Comment: @dvsn, you're right, the coordinates of the rectangle are those... but the solution pointed out gives you the correct answer even if the rectangle is rotated.